# Searching all files in directories and sub-directories that contain specific string and remove string

Tags: c#

A number of PHP files have been compromised on my web server. I need to find the ones that have the issue and remove the problem code. It's taking too long to do manually.

The plan was to provide the top level directory and have the console app search all files in that directory (including ones in sub-directories) and remove the line in each file.

My code is below, it works, but it doesn't seem to look through all directories. Files are correctly updated, but files inside of subdirectories are not. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
public static string check_path = string.Empty;
public static string log_folder = string.Empty;
public static string extension = string.Empty;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args == null || args.Length < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Syntax");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        shakaka(args[0]);
    }
}


public static void shakaka(string check_fol)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(check_fol))
    {
        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(check_fol);
        foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
                if (extension == ".php")
                {
                    var oldLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
                    var newLines = oldLines.Where(line => !line.Contains("/*457563643*/"));
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, newLines);
                    Console.WriteLine("Updated: " + file);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not a PHP File: " + file);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Directory Doesn't Exist: " + check_fol);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Look at your code: you call `Directory.GetDirectories`, which gets the subfolders of `check_fol` and then loops through them. Nowhere are you looping through the subfolders of `check_fol`'s subfolders, etc. Perhaps you wanted the other [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetDirectories_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) which you can instruct to recurse into subdirectories?

Comment: Or use a recursive call, the easiest way to honor this website name (because if you miss with a recursive you get a stackoverflow exception)

Comment: Your code would be much faster if you retrieve only your target files, you can filter your GetFiles call. Check the overloads, as John pointed out there is one that can filter by extension and look into all the subdirectories. In the doc [there is a code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?view=netframework-4.7.2) that does a pretty similar thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you have to do is, make proper use of the overloaded method [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2) which accepts three params. ie., [string path, string searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

The modified code will be like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder,"*.php", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Here

> The first parameter(path) specifies the relative or absolute path
>   to the directory to search. This string is not case-sensitive.
>
> Second parameter(searchPattern) The search string to match against the names of files in path. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters, but it doesn't support regular expressions. *in your case you need only `.php` files so it should be `*.php`
>
> And the last param (SearchOption) One of the enumeration values that specifies whether the search operation should include all subdirectories or only the current directory.